# .Net session , how to get data

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, session

I have a login page called login.aspx that copies the affid into a session and loads the affid on another page called dashboard.aspx.

I collect the session and load it like this :

Login.aspx :

```
MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from mdxmain.taffiliate where affID = '" & username.Text & "' and affPassword = '" & password.Text & "'"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            Session("affID") = username.Text
```

dashboard.aspx :

```
Dim userid As String = HttpContext.Current.Session("affID")
        If (userid Is Nothing) Then
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx")


    End If

Dim c As New MySqlConnection("Server=test;Database=test;UID=test;PWD=test;")
        c.Open()
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand("SELECT AffID FROM toutcome WHERE affID = '" & CType(Session.Item("affID"), String) & "'", c)
        Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        myReader.Read()
        affiliateid.Text = myReader.Item(0).ToString()

        myReader.Close()
```

The problem is that it only collects "affid" from  the database and i have mutiple feilds that i want to use. how do i load all the feilds so i can use them ? So in the mysql query i want to search feilds based on data in the session.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but what would happen if a user has a comma in his password?

Comment: I give out the usernames and passwords, it a website script not many people will use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net session can hold any information that is serializable, so as pointed out you can store whole objects in it if you want, and retrieve fields as needed.

Having said that, I would caution against storing too much sensitive information (like password) in the session as it is generally an antipattern to do so.

We use a wrapper object for our session use that initializes up from HTTPContext, and makes sure we never pass in or use any web specific code in our sub objects while still allowing the overall concept of a session.

So something like this:

```
Public Class UserSession

    Public Property UserName as String = String.Empty

    Public Sub New(context as HTTPContext)
        ...
        Me.Username = CStr(context.Session("UserName"))
    End Sub

    Public Sub Synchronize(context As HTTPContext)
        ....
        context.Session("UserName") = Me.Username
    End Sub

End Class
```

And on the login you now could change it to:

```
Dim us = New UserSession(HttpContext.Current)

MysqlConn.Open()
Dim Query As String
Query = "select * from mdxmain.taffiliate where affID = '" & username.Text & "' and affPassword = '" & password.Text & "'"
COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)

us.UserName = username.Text
... Set any other properties you need ...
us.Synchronize(HttpContext.Current)
```

And then on the page you can just do:

```
Dim us = New UserSession(HttpContext.Current)

DoStuff(us.UserName)
```

Edit:
I just realized that I didn't really give you details of how to set  the properties initially. You can do it one of two ways.

One is to do it exactly like you were in your example (Session("SomeKey") = "SomeValue") Which is actually how we manage ours due to a unique login process. Essentially the object as-is is read-only since no changes are persisted (and this is how we want it) but that may not be the best for everyone.

The perhaps better way if you will want to change the values as you go would be to implement a "Synchronize" method to store properties back to the session. This would handle the initial loading, and any changes after the fact.

You also could back the properties directly on the session if you didn't want the extra step.

See edited method above.

Comment: Hi Tim , thank you , could you please provide a bit more information, i tryed your example, but still cant get it to work. I am new to vb.net.

Comment: I would be glad to, what issue are you running into?

Comment: I re-edited my code above, that is what i am using and i cant get it to work, where am i going wrong ?

Comment: OK, so I guess I mean how is it not working. Are you getting exceptions? Are the values not persisting? Is it just not building? I will make an edit to make one step a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In similar scenarios I create a class for my object... in this case I'll call it User

The User class will have several properties such as Name, AccessRights etc.

The class is populated in the login.aspx code and assigned to a session.

All subsequent pages that need to check user credentials will have the following

```
Private CurrentUser as New User

Protected Sub PageLoad(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Me.PageLoad

    If IsNothing(Session("USER")) Then
       Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
    Else
       CurrentUser = Session("USER")
    End If

End Sub
```

You can then access any user details with `CurrentUser.NameOfProperty` e.g. `CurrentUser.Name` or `CurrentUser.AccessRights` etc.

Comment: Hi Mych , thank you , could you please provide a bit more information, i tryed your example, but still cant get it to work. I am new to vb.net.